# org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I am migrating my java web application from Jboss 7.1.1 Final to Wildfly 10,using :

- spring 4.2.0,
- hibernate 5.0.7,
- jpa 2.1
- and Mysql database.

  I getting the following error while trying to run my code.

> 2016-07-20 19:30:50,176 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."ccp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ccp-entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#ccpPU":
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."ccp-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ccp-entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar#ccpPU":
>   **java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype**
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype     at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:213)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:365)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:166)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:160)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:318)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$1100(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:67)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
>     ... 7 more

Answer (score 1):

- You need  to delete the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and move the configuration from this file to `persistence.xml`.
- Then You have also to remove all hibernate files from `WEB-INF/lib` folder, because **WildFly** has its own ones and this situation also possibly made a conflict. 
  More details on this problem in this link : [JBoss Community Forum](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/238096?_sscc=t)

Comment: 1) I didnt used hibernate.cfg.xml, have configured in persistence.xml. 2) i have added all hibernate maven dependencies in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue with Wildfly 10.0.0.Final. In my project also we have all hibernate related libraries within the project's lib directory. But the jboss provided libraries caused conflicts so i have removed the content within the tag `<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.hibernate">` in `module.xml` file available in `JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\hibernate\main` directory. Also i have removed the dependencies of hibernate libraries in `jboss-deployment-struture.xml` as,

`<exclusions>
<module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
</exclusions>`

After these changes i can able overcome the conflict issues related to hibernate.Hope this will help.

Please note `jboss-deployment-struture.xml` change alone has not resolved my issue the change mentioned on module.xml file is mandatory.